# Lightning Web Components and Salesforce Data: Handle Server Errors

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, trailhead

When I try to deploy my contactList component I see the following error:

No MODULE named `markup://c:ldsUtils` found : `[markup://c:contactList]`

How should I `import ldsUtils` into my js file?

Comment: Did you successfully deploy your ldsUtils component? That is the most common reason for this error, an unsuccessful deployment of dependent metadata.

Comment: @sfdcfox How do deploy the component? The instructions do not appear to readily disclose this process.

Comment: However you're deploying whatever is you're deploying now, just deploy that other bundle as well. VS Code you should be able to deploy via GUI, sfdx force:source:push or sfdx force:source:deploy, etc.

Comment: This could also be an issue with letter case in the import statement. Check that you exactly match the name. Is it IdsUtils or idsUtils, for example?

Comment: did you get any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

[image: Click the LWC Recipe link and download the files]
Source: Salesforce Module - Lightning Web Components and Salesforce Data

Go to the external LWC link and Download the JS and JS-Meta file to your directory. Create another **ldsUtils** folder in **lwc** folder and save in them.

[image: My VSCode pic]
Source: From my PC

Now while deploying, there won't be any error.

Comment: Please include citations as text rather than images.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Is it good now?

Comment: No, you didn't put any of the citation in as text.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that is still needing to resolve this issue, you can head to the following repository with instructions:
[github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes)

I just created the folder `.../lwc/ldsUtils` and copied the files in this folder across and deployed them:
https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/main/force-app/main/default/lwc/ldsUtils/

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I completely understand your position. However, short of pasting the full 81 line file which may likely change in the interim I thought this to be the best compromise. Either way, I'm just hoping this helps someone else out where it could have saved me trying to figure around for the answer 